# Ora Error - 06553 - Wrong number of arguments in a call

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I created a type as below:

```
create   type colist_array as table of varchar(3);
```

Created function:

```
create or replace function  sel_tst(colm_lst  colist_array)
return      colist_array
as
--Declaration and Initialization
a  colist_array := colist_array();

begin

for i in 1..colm_lst.count
loop
  a.extend;
  a(i):= colm_lst(i);

end loop;

return (a);

end;
```

Now when am calling, it throws error -

> wrong number of arguments

Any suggestions here please.

```
 select sel_tst('XXY') from dual;  -- Not working
 select sel_tst('XXY,SDD,DFS')   from dual; -- Not working
 select sel_tst('XXY','YDY') from dual;  -- Not working
```

Comment: Your function expects a **single** parameter (which is an array). You are calling it with **two** parameters.

Comment: Also you should use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`

Comment: @vercelli: that doesn't matter. `varchar` is an alias for `varchar2`

Comment: @vercelli..I dont need varchar2. And even if i change it's not working

Comment: From Oracle Docs: "The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings."

Comment: Its not working even if i change it to varchar2

Comment: Changing `varchar` to `varchar2` won't fix any code but it is just good practice, as Oracle have always said they might change `varchar` in a future release (presumably to make it treat empty strings the way some other RDBMS products do). They have being saying this for 25 years of course, but I would stick to the standard `varchar2` all the same.

Comment: Thanks for making this brilliant explanation. My question was not if my type is correct or not. My question was related to select and i guess it has been beautifully answered by a gentleman here. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function expects a **single** parameter of type `colist_array`. You are calling it with one or more `varchar` parameters.

The correct syntax to create an instance of your type is e.g.: `colist_array('XXY','SDD','DFS')`

So your select statement should be:

```
select sel_tst(colist_array('XXY','SDD','DFS'))
from dual;
```